# Azure AKS Deployment with Azure RBAC Permissions problem

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, rbac

I am attempting to deploy a Proof of Concept Restful API into our AKS Cluster. The Cluster has the Authentication set to "Azure AD Authentication with Azure RBAC". My understanding is that utilizing this Authentication setup will allow the OOTB Azure Roles the ability to control/manage the Cluster.
I have set my account the "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Writer" role.

When I try to create a new "QuickStart Application", on the deployment page, I cannot create a new Namespace for the container. I receive the following message:

"Failed to create namespace ... User cannot create namespaces in API group at the Cluster Scope"

I'm stumped and not sure what permissions I need to set

Any ideas?

I have tried adding multiple different Azure OOTB roles to my account and none seem to make any difference. The roles I have added are:
Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role
Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role
Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin

Comment: You  can edit the clusterrole and add namespace API group and set VERB as create

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you referring to the ClusterRole in K8 or in Azure?

Comment: From the  kubernetes end

Comment: OK but I thought that the Azure RBAC setting allowed me to manage permissions in Azure and not K8

Comment: The plot thickens ... I have enabled the "Kubernetes Local Accounts" checkbox on the Configuration page and when I log into the cluster and execute the kubectl create namespace command, it works. However when I try to create a namespace in the Azure Portal, I get the same message

Comment: It means that you don't have permissions from Azure portal to create a namespace

Comment: I understand that however I'm not sure how to set the permissions so the Azure Portal can create namespaces

Comment: And I have the "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin" role assigned to my account but I still can't create Namespaces in the Portal

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already sorted this, but I had the same issues today and I wanted to share that auth worked after I added these two permissions to the cluster:

- Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role
- Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Writer

To clarify: I didn't have to amend clusterRoles or enable local accounts